# Django forms: reasons to use them?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Are there any real reason to use builtin forms in django?

One of them as I understand is validation. Ok. And maybe some convinience (but not for me).

Anything else?

Is there any acceleration in site work with forms?

Comment: "Re-inventing the wheel" can be a good learning experience, but unless you are constrained by your design I don't see a reason not to use them?

Comment: Do you know anything about acceleration with django-form vs html-forms?

Comment: What do you mean by "acceleration"?

Comment: I mean speed comparison with using django-form vs html-forms.

Comment: Of course using Django forms will be slower, since the templates have to be processed, but on any reasonable modern machine the difference will be withing the margin of error. What Django forms is good at is saving time for the developer, not having to make code that already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more built-in forms, the less work for developers. You are free to implement them from 0 but it is always faster to use something that is already done and tested.

Anyway, you have something in the middle: inherit from built-in forms and customize them.

Answer (score 5):

From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) -

> While it is possible to process form submissions just using Django’s
>   HttpRequest class, using the form library takes care of a number of
>   common form-related tasks. Using it, you can:
>
> 1. Display an HTML form with automatically generated form widgets.
> 2. Check submitted data against a set of validation rules.
> 3. Redisplay a form in the case of validation errors.
> 4. Convert submitted form data to the relevant Python data types.

Also django forms provide some level of security by enforcing [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Some of the [cool things](http://agiliq.com/blog/2010/01/doing-things-with-django-forms/) you can do with django forms

Comment: The django CSRF implementation is not provided by the forms as much as they are provided by the middleware.  Django forms merely provide the shortcut for including the CSRF token, which you can do very easily without django forms.  However, the middleware will refuse to accept POSTs without the csrfmiddlewaretoken whether you use Django forms or not...

Answer (score 3):

I agree that in some circumstances, the temptation to avoid the use of Django form is very strong.

If I need just one field with no validation nor style, why should I define a django-form?

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' action='url_to_my_view'>
    Type something: <input type='text' name='any_value'/>
</form>
```

Django:

```
<form method='POST' action='url_to_my_view'>
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

with the overhead of defining the form and including it in the view.

But I still use Django-forms: experience tells me that software shortcuts always lead to problems...